# setuid not working on a script

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, fstab, setuid

I'm working on a RHEL 6.7 machine. I'd like to make a script which is owned by root BUT could be launched by other users. However I still want the actions inside the script to be launched as root. So I want to set the suid bit on this script. Right now I have the following results:

```
[root@devmachine BACKUP]# chmod a+s fix_properties.sh
[root@devmachine BACKUP]# ls -halt fix_properties.sh
-r-sr-s-r-x 1 root root 42 May 12 00:08 fix_properties.sh
```

This is not good enough since a lambda user would be able to execute it but wouldn't benefit from the root permissions. After some digging I learned that it could be due to the way the FS is mounted. When I check the fstab file I see the following:

```
/dev/mapper/systemvg-op /opt ext3 defaults,nosuid,nodev 1 2
...
/dev/systemvg/opt_backup /opt/BACKUP ext4 acl,user_xattr 1 2
```

Does this mean that the `nosuid` will be also *de rigueur* on the `/opt/BACKUP` partition?

As a work-around, I guess I could assign this file to a particular group from which my target user is part of?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/1209.  Short answer, you should probably be using sudo to delegate permissions to run the script as root.

Comment: See also [Allow setuid on shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364/80216).